# Backward in time integration of numerical ODE

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-methods, numerical-integration

I have an array of size (n, 2, 2) that represent A( x(t), u(t) ), x[n] and u[n] been one dimensional arrays. I have the equation

p'(t) = A( x(t), u(t) ) p(t) , with the final condition been p(T) = p_T.

The x and u where generated by solving an optimization problem with timesteps been np.linspace(0,T,nt). Now I want to integrate the above equation, reading throught other answers it seems that the odeint from SciPy can handle the backward time integration out of the box.

Since for each pair ( x(t), u(t) ) I have the aforementioned (n, 2, 2) array, should I have to create an intepolation for the matrix A(x(t), u(t)) ? The griddata seems to be the right way of doing it, but I don´t know how to input the time, once the odeint function requires it.

My question is, in summary, given timesteps np.linspace(0,T,nt), x[n] and u[n] , and a calculated (nt, 2, 2) array that is derived from x and u, how can I pass the system to be integrated (backward in time, from T to 0) with the odeint function from scipy ?

Comment: So the shape of A is (n,2,2) where the fist axis is  the time t with n positions in time. And then you have a value of x and one of u for ich position in time. Ist that the 2nd axis? And what is the 3rd axis? You have a 2by2 matrix for each time step?

Comment: Yes, for each n I have a 2x2 matrix that is constructed with the values of the corresponding x[n], u[n]

Comment: I mean, for each t (n), I have a formula with x and u in the time n that I construct a 2x2 matrix

Comment: x[n] is one value, u[n] is another, but the 2x2 matrix has 4 values...or is there an x1[n] and an x2[n] maybe you share some code snipped how you setup your matrix?

Comment: Yes, indeed x[n] and u[n] are one number. The matrix A is calculated based on the problem modeling, so it is something like

A[n] = np.array([ [x[n]*(1-x[n]) , 1/x[n] * u[n] 
                            [0, u[n]] ])

The formaula isn´t exactly this, but I think this hopefully clarify